# Linux PhpStorm cannot connect to remote server Only SSH2 keys in OpenSSH format

Tags: linux, ssh, phpstorm

I'm trying to create a new project connecting to a remote filesystem. When trying to connect via SSH I get this error:

> Only SSH2 keys in OpenSSH format(DSA, RSA or ECDSA) or PuTTY Private Key *.ppk keys are supported

The error is pretty obvious that my key is wrong even though I'm just using the default id_rsa key my distro comes with which works everywhere else.

After I search I found a command on the JetBrains support page to create a new key correctly:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f <name of file>
```

So I did this yet PhpStorm still complains it's not the correct format.

What do I require to create the correct format SSH key?

Comment: Try using "open ssh config or authentication agent" as Authentication in SFTP deployment server configuration as a workaround. 
Or try to create a key using `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa or ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`. See more details about the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27934 (+ latest comments).

Comment: **[This question is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381930/review-of-the-general-computing-hardware-and-software-rule). All discussion of its topicality or suitableness should be posted there, not here.**

Comment: Make sure to select the file called `id_rsa` and not `id_rsa.pub` when your IDE asks for it.